# error installing exe python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to install the file pokereval-138.win32-py2.7.exe from http://sourceforge.net/projects/fpdb/files/fpdb/pypoker-eval-win32/ but I get an error saying "The file exists. Could not create a temporary file".

I have python 2.7 32-bit installed on a 64-bit Windows 7 pc. I have tried running the file as an administrator but get exactly the same error.

I have installed several other files by double clicking the exe which runs a python 2.7 installer.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this issue. My temp folder was full - once i ran "disk cleanup" and deleted my temp files the installation worked.